# admob in monotouch with alextouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, admob

I have a monotouch application that uses alextouch binding for admob. I added the .dll to my references. This is the .cs file for which I want to add the banners.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        string url = "http://dummy-website-name.php";
        NSUrlRequest req = new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (url));
        WEB.LoadRequest (req);


        var ad = new GADBannerView(GADAdSizeCons.MediumRectangle,new PointF(0,0))
        {
            AdUnitID = "a15179c91adb8e5",
            RootViewController = this
        };
        ad.DidReceiveAd += delegate 
        {
            this.View.AddSubview(ad);
            Console.WriteLine("AD Received");
        };
        ad.DidFailToReceiveAdWithError += delegate(object sender, GADBannerViewDidFailWithErrorEventArgs e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        };
        ad.WillPresentScreen += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("showing new screen");
        };
        ad.WillLeaveApplication += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("I will leave application");
        };
        ad.WillDismissScreen += delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("Dismissing opened screen");
        };
        Console.Write("Requesting Ad");
        ad.LoadRequest(new GADRequest());
}
```

When I run on my iphone ios 6.1 it shows no ad. In debug mode it states admob error: no ad shown. In release mode it says nothing and shows no ad. Am I also to add items to the .m or .h file corresponding to this uiviewcontroller? And obviously I have been using an appropriate publisher id that works in my monodroid app version...

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the official binding repo of Admob which has recently been updated to 6.5.0. This one also comes with a working sample.

Find it here: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAdMobAds

Answer (score 0):

I really should remove that outdated repo :)

You can use the one mentioned by Krumelur, that one us up to date or you can even maje your life easier by using the one in the Xamarin's Component Store that is up to date too!!

http://components.xamarin.com/view/googleadmob/

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Yes I tried using that one on the component store but could not find the GoogleAdMobAds.dll anywhere.